# How to show the result of prediction in percentage in keras?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

The result of output always in one hot format in keras look like:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0. 0. 0. 1. 0]]
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0. 0. 0. 0. 0]]
```

But I want to have a probability percent for each classification, for example

```
[[ 0.54  0.80  0.34  0.041]]
```

My simple code is given below

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model

from new_get_data_for_test import load_my_data

try :
   X_test = load_my_data()

   model = load_model('/home/istiyak/development/pythonProject/my_save_model.h5')

   output = model.predict(X_test)

   print("After pridiction our output is : ")
   print (output)
   print(np.argmax(output, axis=1))

except Exception as e :
   print ("Some Exception occurs")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`predict_proba`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#sequential-model-methods). From the documentation:

> `predict_proba(self, x, batch_size=32, verbose=1)`
>
> Generates class probability predictions for the input samples batch by batch.
>
> Returns a Numpy array of probability predictions.

Comment: I have used predict_proba() function but gives the same result.

Comment: I have also used predict_classes() but don't return the Numpy array of probability predictions @Sergii Gryshkevych

Comment: In such case it seems like there might be some issues with your model. I would start by examining input to the final softmax layer. Starting from some order of magnitude of its inputs softmax might yield "on-hot"-like output. Such problem can be mitigated with regularization.

Comment: What is the classpath for predict_proba() ?